# Помогите найти ошибки в коде

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Где ошибка в коде? В теории код должен работать так чтобы проверять входящие сообщение и отправлять отредактированный ответ исходя из полученного. Если входящие сообщение равно значению переменной $value1 (1), тогда отправленное сообщение должно быть "2", в ином случае вновь "1".

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) { 
    return; 
} 

$value1 = "1";
$otwet_bot = "$value1";
$confirmation_token = '...'; 
$token = '...'; 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

switch ($data->type) { 
    case 'confirmation': 
        echo $confirmation_token; 
        break; 
    case 'message_new': 
        $message = $data->object->body;
        if ($message == "1"){
            $value1 = "2";
            $user_id = $data->object->user_id; 
            $user_info = json_decode(
              file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&v=5.0")
            ); 
            $request_params = array(
                "message" => "$otwet_bot", 
                'user_id' => $user_id, 
                'access_token' => $token, 
                'v' => '5.0' 
            ); 
        }else{
            $value1 = "1";
            $user_id = $data->object->user_id; 
            $user_info = json_decode(
                file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&v=5.0")); 
            $request_params = array(
                "message" => "$otwet_bot", 
                'user_id' => $user_id, 
                'access_token' => $token, 
                'v' => '5.0' 
            ); 
        };
        $get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 
        file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 
        echo('ok'); 
        break; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Что касается смысла жизни. Начните с книги Роберта Мартина "Чистый код", с главы "Горизонтальное форматирование"

Comment: А по существу - ошибки то какие? Что именно не работает?

Comment: Не вижу никакой свзяи с $value1, не вижу никакой разницы в условиях, и мы не знаем что у вас там в json обьекте. В чем собственно у вас проблема?

Comment: @rjhdby Суть в том что условие не выполняется "Если входящие сообщение равно значению переменной $value1 (1), тогда отправленное сообщение должно быть "2", в ином случае вновь "1".".